# Частотная визуализация звука с помощью библиотеки BASS

Tags: c++, delphi, визуализация, fft, фурье

Здравствуйте! Пишу для себя небольшой плеер на C++ Qt и BASS, хочу сделать визуализацию. Почитал информацию по этой теме понял что для этого используют преобразование Фурье. Выяснилось что в BASS уже есть функция для подобных целей, сигнатура выглядит так:

```
DWORD BASS_ChannelGetData(
    DWORD handle,
    void *buffer,
    DWORD length
);
```

где handle- это поток над которым будет выполнено преоброзование, buffer- указатель на массив который будет содержать выходные данные. а вот с третьим  параметром я до конца не разобрался понял только то что он используется для указания размера выходных данных. 
Пробовал писать так:

```
short buffer[256];
BASS_ChannelGetData(_stream, buffer ,BASS_DATA_FFT256);
```

Получается теперь массив buffer содержит данные которые можно визуализировать? или нет? В данном случаи я получил 256 значений но какие из них действительно нужны? пробовал просто отрисовывать это на форме, но выглядело это не очень.  В этом и заключается проблема, я просто не знаю что дальше делать с этими данными,  может нужно еще выполнять какие та вычисления?

Comment: Что значит визуализация звука? Какие параметры вы хотите визуализовать?

Comment: Хочу сделать красивые цветные полосочки прыгающии в такт звука  https://youtu.be/aXD3HGlz65c

Comment: Если вам нужен многополосный измеритель уровня, то никакой фурье не нужен, нужна куча полосных фильтров, которые будут тупо делить сигнал на частотные полосы.

Comment: Извиняюсь за невежество  но как подобное можно реализовать?

Comment: Взять звуковой поток и скормить его полосовому фильтру, затем измерить амплитуду результата и передать визуализатору столбца, и так для N частотных полос.

Comment: А ты уверен что FFT может вернуть в буфер short? По моему там должен быть float[].

Comment: Вроде да, во всяком случаи я не видел там число >=  2^16.  Мне кажется проблема в другом, я похоже не правильно рассчитываю коэффициент, поэтому у меня все очень уродливо выглядит т. е. разницы между этими полосочками практически не видно. Расчет делаю так:   double k =  height / 65535.0; for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) heightElement = buffer[i] * k ...  paint(heightElement);

Answer (score 2):

1. Внимательно читаем описание флага `BASS_DATA_FFT256` в документации (особое внимание тому что в скобках):

> BASS_DATA_FFT256       256 sample FFT (returns 128 floating-point values)

Так что для во-первых не `short`, а `float`, а во-вторых `[128]`, а не `[256]`.

```
float buffer[128]; // вот так правильно
BASS_ChannelGetData(_stream, buffer, BASS_DATA_FFT256);
```

2. В архиве вместе с `bass.dll` лежит куча примеров кода, в том числе и визуализации. Для C++ смотри пример из папки ...\c\spectrum

Answer (score 1):

Размер буфера данных и то, как интерпретировать данные в нем, зависит от разрядности воспроизводимого аудио потока. Читайте [документацию по этой функции](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_ChannelGetData.html), там все написано и даже с примером.